# Docker - Not able to telnet Linked Container

Tags: unix, docker, containers, telnet

I have a **container A** with Dockerfile as follows:

```
...
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER arpitaggarwal "aggarwalarpit.89@gmail.com"
EXPOSE 8080
```

and another **container B** with Dockerfile as follows:

```
...
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER arpitaggarwal "aggarwalarpit.89@gmail.com"
RUN apt-get install -q -y mysql-server
EXPOSE 3306
```

Then I started the **container B** using command:

```
docker run -P -it --name db B /bin/bash
```

And running the command:  `docker run --rm --name web --link db A env`

gives me below output:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=a5dd66b72ca8
DB_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.2:3306
DB_PORT_3306_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.2:3306
DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.2
DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306
DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PROTO=tcp
DB_NAME=/web/db
HOME=/root
```

Then I logged into **container A** and run the command: **ping db**

which gives me **output**:

```
PING db (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from db (172.17.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from db (172.17.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from db (172.17.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from db (172.17.0.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from db (172.17.0.2): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
```

And when I tried `telnet` command with port 3306, as follows:

```
telnet 172.17.0.2 3306
```

gives me output:

```
root@9b078c1fed82:/# telnet 172.17.0.2 3306
Trying 172.17.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Any idea, how can I telnet linked container?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: And you're sure that MySQL is properly installed in B and listening to external connections on the port?

Comment: I installed mysql-client, logged in to mysql-server and perform query operations as well and for outer connections I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL usually only listens on `127.0.0.1` by default. You need to modify the `my.cnf` during build and set `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`. You could accomplish this with something like:

```
RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: It worked, thanks :), also adding the new answer to the question to resolve the connection with mysql after adding `RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf` in DockerFIle.

Answer (score 1):

After receiving the answer by @Andy Shinn, I Updated the **container B** Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER arpitaggarwal "aggarwalarpit.89@gmail.com"
RUN apt-get install -q -y mysql-server
RUN apt-get install -q -y mysql-client
RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
EXPOSE 3306
```

And when I tried accessing **mysql-server** from **container A** as:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -h 172.17.0.2
```

Gives me error:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.17.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Which I figured it out is because container A was trying to connect to db container through root user. **But In mysql do not allow you to connect though root user remotely.** So I work around creating another user in mysql-server with root privileges.